# Number of ways to arrange n elements such that $n_1$ is to the left of $n_2$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How can I find the number of ways to arrange n elements such that $n_1$ is to the left of $n_2$?
This is not restricted to directly to the left. (e.g $n_2$ could be 4 places over to the right.)

So I tried it with a simple example by setting $n=5$, and these are the arrangements I got:

> $n_1, 4, 3, 2, 1$ (if $n_1$ is first, then there are 4 ways to put the second element, and so on)
>
> $3, n_1, 3, 2, 1$
>
> $3, 2, n_1, 2, 1$
>
> $3, 2, 1, n_1, 1$

So, summing all these I got $(4+3+2+1)(3!)$ arrangements. However this approach is not really mathematical and I can't generalize this for all $n$. Is there any other way to get a general answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$n!$ permutations are possible if there is no restriction. Let $A$ be the set of permutations with $n_1$ to the left of $n_2$ and $B$ the set of permutations with $n_2$ to the left of $n_1$. Define $f:A\to B$ with $f$ sending a permutation to one with $n_1$ and $n_2$ interchanged. This is a bijection, and so $|A|=|B|=n!/2$.

Comment: can you elaborate on why half of these permutations have $n_1$ to the right and left? Thanks!

Comment: @rola For each permutation that has $n_1$ to the left of $n_2$, there is a single corresponding permutation, obtained by switching $n_1$ and $n_2$, that has $n_1$ to the right of $n_2$.  Since the permutations with $n_1$ on the left are in one-to-one correspondence with the ones that have $n_1$ on the right, the numbers of the two kinds of permutations is equal.

Comment: @MJD Yeah, I just realised that it was a bijection. Thanks for the answer